# Terminal Voltage of Battery

Tags: batteries

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ3eP4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$\Delta V = \Delta V_1 + \Delta V_2 $$

Can we apply this equation for this circuit? I mean what does this equation stand for?  As seen, there are two batteries with opposite polarity.  I also know that

$$\Delta V = + \epsilon$$

$$\Delta V = - \epsilon$$

Which are the potential difference of batteries. If you explain that equation refers to, I'd be grateful.

Regards!

Comment: Can anyone take a look at it?

Comment: Why are you commenting to yourself? If you're not getting answers it may be because the question is bad. There is nothing marked ΔV in your diagram and +ϵ and -ϵ aren't shown either.

Comment: \$\Delta\$ normally means ‘a change in...’, it seems superfluous in this circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blindly applying formulas, how about you try writing a Kirchhoff's Voltage law loop. Kirchhoff's Voltage law states that:

> The algebraic sum of the voltages in a closed loop is equal to 0.

So how do you sum the voltages? First, you pick a direction that you think the current will flow, and a point to start summing. I'm going to pick the bottom left corner, and I think current will flow counter clockwise. Next, you sum the voltage across each component, using the sign in the direction you're going. For B2, since I'm going counterclockwise, I reach the positive before the negative so I write $$ B2 + ... = 0 $$
Next, I reach B1, but this time I see the negative sign first, so I write $$B2 + -B1 + ... = 0$$

Next you reach the resistors. Since they don't have any +/- markings, you have to write them in. In this case, since we think the current will be flowing counterclockwise, the side of the resistor that the current is flowing towards will be the positive side. So I will mark both R1 and R2 with a + sign on the right. Then like the batteries, we sum the voltages across the resistors. $$B2 - B1 + VR1 + VR2 = 0$$
Finally, we solve for the voltage across the two resistors
$$VR1+VR2 = B1 - B2$$
From this, we can determine that the voltage across the resistors from right to left (counterclockwise in the circuit) is \$B1 - B2 = 5 - 10 = -5V\$.

Comment: Assume that the batteries was connected in parallel, How would you solve it?

Comment: Also did you use the rule $$\Delta V = \Delta V_1 + \Delta V_2$$

Comment: You can't have an ideal 5V supply in parallel to an ideal 10V supply.

Comment: @Morata no, it’s not very instructive to use that equation and it’s susceptible to errors if you don’t pay careful attention to signs. However if you look at my final equation you can see the result appears like the  \$\delta V\$ equation.